# Navigating back in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a Visualforce page with a list of records(users search records based on criteria) and they can create tasks/take some other action on the records they want to work upon. My question is - In SF1, after creating a task if I try to go back, my whole list is lost and the users have to search the records again. In the desktop- I can use browser tabs and my list remains intact. However there are no tabs in SF1 downloadable app. What are my options here to direct the user back to the Visualforce page with out a refresh.

Comment: Does anyone have any comments?